# Wifi working then not working and so forth

Tags: wireless

Good day everyone,

My wifi connection has been rather moody since yesterday; it's funky because it all started with me trying to convert a video in VLC (the correlation is not very clear to me, although when vlc eventually failed to do it and just stopped, the wifi worked again).
So it just won't connect at all, and then sometimes it will and the wifi will work, and sometimes it will just stop working but will stay connected.
It's definitely not a problem with my router, because every other computer and device is working all smooth.
Furthermore, the same thing is happening if i boot with windows (i have partitionned my HDD in two pieces, one with ubuntu 16.04 and the other with windows 10).

My guess is that maybe the wifi card is failing on me? it's slowly but surely stopping to fulfill its duty? What do you guys think?
Here's a bunch of infos that you may need to understand the problem (sorry, i just don't...), and that another topic suggested to put.
( [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) )
Sorry if it's a bit of a mess in here, i'm putting it all...
thanks a lot in advance!

(it misses some info i cut because of character number)

```
########## wireless info START ##########


01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:089d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e07f]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k


##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

acer_wmi               20480  0
ath3k                  20480  0
bluetooth             520192  30 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
ath9k                 147456  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              737280  1 ath9k
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
cfg80211              565248  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
sparse_keymap          16384  2 acer_wmi,intel_vbtn
wmi                    20480  1 acer_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915,acer_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1473055 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:439312 (439.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:126982 (126.9 KB)  TX bytes:126982 (126.9 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.43  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5624:eca2:b7ef:97ac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2408 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1269099 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:536039 (536.0 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"freebro"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'freebro' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=36 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:249  Invalid misc:135   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       861     1  0 10:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath9k
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-83-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     freebro
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       68fb7de9-fbbe-498f-a78a-970aca509dff
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     36 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0,3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   fd98afa1-6291-4ba6-9c42-34535a4aa6cc | freebro_EXT
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   68fb7de9-fbbe-498f-a78a-970aca509dff | freebro
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.43/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.254
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.254
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1499717079
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.0.254
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.43
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.254
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.254
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::5624:eca2:b7ef:97ac/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         40 (Carrier/link changed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID             BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY     ACTIVE  * 
freebro_EXT      <MAC 'freebro_EXT' [AC6]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WEP          no        
FreeWifi         <MAC 'FreeWifi' [AC5]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  --           no        
FreeWifi_secure  <MAC 'FreeWifi_secure' [AC4]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X  no        
freebro          <MAC 'freebro' [AC1]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WEP          yes     * 
SFR_2D90         <MAC 'SFR_2D90' [AN5]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  12      ▂___  WPA1         no        
FreeWifi_secure  <MAC 'FreeWifi_secure' [AN6]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  9       ▂___  WPA2 802.1X  no        
Freebox-0A4899   <MAC 'Freebox-0A4899' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  5       ____  WPA2         no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/freebro_EXT]] (600 root)
[connection] id=freebro_EXT | type=wifi | permissions=user:elkevn:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=freebro_EXT
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Unice-HotSpot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Unice-HotSpot | type=wifi | permissions=user:elkevn:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Unice-HotSpot
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/freebro]] (600 root)
[connection] id=freebro | type=wifi | permissions=user:elkevn:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=freebro
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Bbox-3178B9A3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Bbox-3178B9A3 | type=wifi | permissions=user:elkevn:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Bbox-3178B9A3
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Paris (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      4   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'freebro' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"freebro"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                              6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000cf8433cd1
                    Extra: Last beacon: 168ms ago
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Freebox-0A4899' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Freebox-0A4899"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                              6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000738ee15815f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4664ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'FreeWifi' [AC3]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=16/70  Signal level=-94 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"FreeWifi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                              6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000738ee15816e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4632ms ago
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'FreeWifi_secure' [AC4]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FreeWifi_secure"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                              6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000cf85f8160
                    Extra: Last beacon: 200ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'FreeWifi' [AC5]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"FreeWifi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                              6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000cf842ca48
                    Extra: Last beacon: 136ms ago
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'freebro_EXT' [AC6]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"freebro_EXT"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000cf775416d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 160ms ago

last dmesg entries:
[ 6214.062879] wlp2s0: authenticate with 14:0c:76:ed:11:00
[ 6214.086700] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 1/3)
[ 6214.926271] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 2/3)
[ 6215.092807] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 3/3)
[ 6215.927435] wlp2s0: authentication with 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 timed out
[ 6219.936067] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 6227.715697] wlp2s0: authenticate with 14:0c:76:ed:11:00
[ 6227.733016] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 1/3)
[ 6228.738444] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 2/3)
[ 6229.744001] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 3/3)
[ 6230.749314] wlp2s0: authentication with 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 timed out
[ 6241.637586] wlp2s0: authenticate with 14:0c:76:ed:11:00
[ 6241.656315] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 1/3)
[ 6242.660385] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 2/3)
[ 6243.665963] wlp2s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 (try 3/3)
[ 6244.671956] wlp2s0: authentication with 14:0c:76:ed:11:00 timed out
[ 6245.174425] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Can you try the answers to [this similar question](/q/829048/175814) please? You can also [search for other questions about flaky connections with this chipset](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aaskubuntu.com+"AR9565"|"QCA9565").

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion David Foerster, though no solution has helped thus far unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

so i found the solution to my problem, in this case it actually had to do with the wifi router.
It was broadcasting with a WEP encryption key, which was obsolete. Furthermore, when i was typing the command

```
nmcli dev wifi
```

the result included "WPA1 WPA2" when it came to the "security" column.
The solution was for me to change that in the routers' settings.

Another thing I did (and I'm not entirely sure as to how that helped or not) was to disable the secure boot in the bios (F2 when starting the computer). Although mine was greyed out, it sufficed to install an admin password for the bios to get it modifiable.

I hope this ever helps someone later! take care

Comment: Please add additional information TO YOUR QUESTION. Don't post it as an answer.

Comment: how do i do that? the original question exceeded the 30000 characters limit... sorry if i'm missing something obvious here

Comment: This means that the script has too much info. Anyway this "answer" will be deleter by mods as "not an answer". I think the problem is at the AP side.

Comment: do you mean that you think the problem comes from my router? it actually doesn't, because every other connected device works just great, it's just my computer experiencing trouble ... thanks :)